# What is the time complexity of this algorithm using nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
int algo(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = i; j <= n; j *= 2)
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

My calculation is:

[image: calculation process]

But by executing the code, I found that the complexity is about `2n` = `O(n)`.

Have I miscalculated or can the expression be simplified?

Comment: Why do you have `n/i` in your first term? In my opinion it should be `sum_i=1^n log (i)` because in the first iteration of the outer loop you have `log(n)` iterations of the inner loop, in the second you have `log(n-1)`, in the third `log(n-2)` ... `log_2(n-n+1)` , ie the sum of all `log(n) +log(n-1) + ... + log(1)`. Which leads to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589027/whats-the-formula-to-solve-summation-of-logarithms

Comment: @derpirscher variable `j` starts at `i = 2^{start}` and ends at `n = 2^{end}`, because `j` multiply by 2 every iteration, so the inner loop iterated `end - start = log n - log i = log n/i` times.

Comment: `j` starts at the current `i` of the outer loop. The `i` of the outer loop starts at `1` is incremented in steps of `1` (ie `i++`) until it reaches `n`. Thus the first iteration of the inner loop is from `1 .. n`, the second is from `2..n` the third is from `3..n` and so on. Unless you based your calculations on a different code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your results are correct: your complex result can indeed be simplified. You need [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) of the factorial for that.

Stirling's approximation "sandwiches" the factorial between two similar expressions, but you need only the lower bound:

```
log2(n!) > n * log2(n) - n * log2(e)
```

Then:

```
log2(n^n) = n * log2(n)
log2(n^n / n!) = log2(n^n) - log2(n!)
log2(n^n / n!) < [n * log2(n)] - [n * log2(n) - n * log2(e)]
```

Simplify the right side:

```
[n * log2(n)] - [n * log2(n) - n * log2(e)] = n * log2(e) = O(n)
```

---

Informally, `n! ≈ (n/e)^n`. Plug this into your expression, and you get `log2(e^n)`, or `O(n)`. This is what I actually did to judge your expression quickly, but you need to be more rigorous than that if you want to prove it.

Comment: Can the Taylor expantion used to prove this? `e^n = 1 + n^1/1! + ... + n^n/n! > n^n/n!`, so `log n^n/n! < log e^n = n log e`. But the series is expanded at `n = 0`, I wonder it can be used when `n -> +\infty`.

Comment: Maybe you can use use it, but not immediately: there are more terms after `n^n/n!` in the expansion of the exponent.